# Curl Check if a domain is root

Tags: php, curl

Hello I am trying to make a little spider. 
While I was building it I came across a problem where I need to check if a link is a root domain link or a subdomain link.

For example:

```
http://www.domain.com or
http://domain.com 
http://domain.com/index.php
http://domain.com/default.php
http://domain.com/index.html
http://domain.com/default.html
```

.
.
etc
are all the same.

So I need a function actually that takes the string url as an input and checks if it's the root or homepage whatever you like to call it of a site.

Comment: technically www.domain.com and domain.com are NOT the same, www is a subdomain that most people always point to their domain.com, just like hello.domain.com is a subdomain.

Comment: Don't assume that all sites are going to use this convention.  It is entirely possible to have different sites at each of these URLs.  If I were you, I'd hash the content and use that to compare against what you have already loaded.

Comment: Should it compare the contents? Isn't www.domain.com a subdomain to domain.com?

Comment: The thing is, *are* they all the same? I'm guessing that you'd get at least a couple of `404 Not Found`s on my sites (`default.php`? Definitely not found around here), a bunch of `301` redirects (for `www.domain.com` and `index.php`), and perhaps some actual pages.

Comment: Those are all distinct URLs, they *might* resolve to the same content, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Quentin you are right those are all unique pages or could be, and as Brad mentiond, it points out that the only true way to check if those pages are similar is the content it self. But there is no guarantee as i can think of. If there is a way to grab the type of file i am fetching? for example if i hit a page domain.com is there a way to tell that the page type is index.php or default.php or anything.something?

Comment: @themhz — No. There might not even be "a file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, this is really a basic aspect of coding the spider. If you intend to code a general purpose spider, you'll need to add means to resolve URLs and detect if they point to the same content and in what way (through a redirect or simply through duplicate content), as well as what kind of content they point to.

You need at least to handle:

- relative paths
- GET-variables that are in one way or another significant to the web page, but does not render differences in the content.
- Malformed URLs.
- JavaScript related information in the href attribute.
- Links to non-HTML material -- direct download links to PDFs, images etc. (detect it on extension isn't always enough, what with PHP scripts delivering images).

These are just some of the aspects but it all comes down to the point that the kind of detection your after have to be a fundamental part of the spider if you intend to use it in any kind of generic manner.

Comment: zrvan thanks, Ι think you are right. Actually I like when Ι am codeing to make things useful for future usage, so i am on general coding :). 
I think that taking in account the content of a page, solves the problem of page uniqueness. since two url's have the same content then those two "pages" are similar or same despite the fact that the urlpath within the domain is different.
So now I come to a problem were I need to compare two large strings and fast.

Comment: @themhz: to do this one would generally use a hash, depending on the needs of the spider, you have to choose between a fast algorithm with collision risks (for instance, md5) or a slower one with low-to-none risk of collision (for instance something in the sha-family), check the timing table by `luka8088 at gmail dot com` over here: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php . But this is really the topic of a new SO question.